# Weird iPad Browser Quirk/ CSS Issue

Tags: css, ios, browser, rendering, quirks-mode

I'm working on a page (http://oscarspad.co.uk/Gallery/) which uses the Galleria plugin to generate an image browser. All is fine *except* when the page is viewed on iPads.

In this scenario the page body content moves way over to the right while everything else stays as it is.

Can anyone shed any light on this? I've tested the page on all major browsers under Win and Mac, and also on my HTC Desire HD with both Opera and HTC's own browser.

Comment: works fine in iOS5. What is your iOS version?

Comment: I have no problem in the iPad simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems with my iPad 2 running iOS 5.
http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/sn0aerbs/Foto.PNG

Comment: Many thanks for the sanity check - I'll have to see if the client is running an ipad or an ipad2. I suspect the former with ios< 5.